# ODEs in the space of distributions $\mathcal{D}'(a,b)$: some general solution technique.

Tags: functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, distribution-theory

I am studying ordinary differential equations in the space of distribution $\mathcal{D}'$ where $\mathcal{D}$ is the space of bump (aka test) functions.
The equations we treat are linear, although not always with constant coefficients. What my instructor does to solve this equations is the following

1. Either resorting directly to the lemma which states that $T'=0\ in\
       \mathcal{D}'\Rightarrow T=constant$, in the simplest cases
2. In less trivial cases, such as, say $u'+a(x)u=0$ with
   $a(x)\in C^\infty$, she exploits some kind of 'suggestions' from the
   classical solution and, given some $\phi\in\mathcal{D}$ she lets the
   derivative acts on a term $e^{-A(x)}\phi$,   instead of on $\phi$
   alone, where $A(x)$ is a primitive of $a(x)$: hence $\phi$ multiplied by the classical solution of the equation. This leads to a
   convenient rewriting of the equation which allows to exploit the
   lemma of point 1.

I can smell the idea of the tecnique, but since this is done without justification, I would like to know if this is just an euristic or a general approach. We pretty soon moved to partial differential equations, where through the fundamental solution of an operator and convolution one does get a general approach so any help, suggestion or explanation would be great.

Comment: About $T' = 0 \implies T  = C$. Iff $<1,\phi> = 0$ then $\phi = \Phi'$ in the test functions thus take $\psi$ such that $<1,\psi > =1$ let $C= <T,\psi>$ then  $$<T,\varphi>-<C,\varphi> =  <T,\varphi-<1,\varphi>\psi> =<T,\Phi'> = -<T',\Phi> = 0$$

Comment: Isn't it justification enough that $e^A (u'+A'u) = (e^A u)'$ and that multiplication with $e^A$ doesn't change the set of solutions since $e^A \neq 0$?

Comment: @reuns, your one line proof is much more direct that the one shown during the course, +1, although I did not have many problems with that!

Comment: @md2perpe I really struggle to understand this kind of comments in this site. Please, read my question. My doubt is not about the sepcific instance of the equation you mention, but about a general approach. Say you were mister Schwartz, say you were the Cristopher Columbus of this kind of problems. What would suggest to adopt such a technique as the one I showed as an instnce. I perfectly understand the example I proposed, I am trying to understand if or why things work out this way in general.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course these techniques have to be justified.

Assume that we have a distributional differential equation $u' + A'u = v,$ where $u$ is an unknown distribution, $A$ is a given $C^\infty$ function, and $v$ is a given distribution.

From the classical theory, we get the idea of multiplying $u' + A'u$ with the integrating factor $e^A$. This part is no problem; also in distribution theory it is valid that $e^A (u' + A'u) = (e^A u)'$.

But will multiplication with $e^A$ preserve the set of solutions? Is $e^A w = 0$ equivalent with $w = 0$ for every distribution $w$? Indeed it is, and the reason for this is that $e^{-A} \in C^\infty$ since $e^A \neq 0$ everywhere:

Let $\varphi \in C_c^\infty$. If $w=0$ then it is clear that $e^A w=0$ since $\langle e^A w, \varphi \rangle = \langle w, e^A \varphi \rangle = 0$. On the other hand, if $e^A w = 0$ then
$\langle w, \varphi \rangle = \langle w, e^A e^{-A} \varphi \rangle = \langle e^A w, e^{-A} \varphi \rangle = 0,$ since $e^{-A} \varphi \in C_c^\infty$.

Thus, multiplying $u'+A'u=v$ with $e^A$ doesn't change the set of solutions. Therefore $e^A(u'+A'u)=e^A v$ is equivalent to the initial equation. But this is equivalent with $(e^A u)' = e^A v$. Now we only have to find all primitive distributions $w$ for $e^A v$ to get $e^A u = w,$ and then multiply with the nonzero factor $e^{-A}$ to get $u = e^{-A} w.$